# Can aquafaba be used to replace gluten in breads and buns?

Tags: cooking, egg-substitutes

Having made a surprisingly good Pavlova from aquafaba (non-brined chick pea juice - the liquid from the can), I was wondering whether it was possible to use the egg-like properties of this juice to replace gluten in breads and buns?
Does it work in this way?

Comment: Are you attempting gluten-free, rather than egg-free? I'm wondering whether this is specifically vegetarian-related; if not, I could migrate to Seasoned Advice.

Comment: The question was about gluten-free cooking but also has useful application in egg-free cooking hence the vegetarian classification.

Answer (score 3):

No. When kneaded, the gluten in flour such as wheat, barley, etc. traps the gas released by the fermentation process and make the dough raise. Aquafaba can in some cases replace egg white, but not gluten.

In gluten free bread, psyllium husk or xanthan gum are normally used to allow the dough to raise.